# a very confusing problem about python multiprocessing

Tags: python

I get a problem in my job to filter file ,for example,if i run this code first,it is slow,and run until global_step=100000,then i terminate this code,then i run again,it will fast until global_step=100000,then it will slow.i can't find why it happened like this,can someone give me a advise,i have a poor english

```py
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process, Value
read_dir = '..'
write_dir ='..'
dict_dir = '..'
Q_read = Queue(10000)
Q_write = Queue(10000)
global_step = Value('i', 0)
def Push_queue(Q_read, r_dir):
    f = open(r_dir, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        Q_read.put(line)
    f.close()

def Write_from_Queue(Q_write, w_dir):
    fw = open(w_dir, 'w')
    while True:
        try:
            line = Q_write.get(timeout=30)
            fw.write(line)
            fw.flush()
        except:
            fw.close()
            return



def asy_run(Q_read, Q_write, global_step, char2ind_dict):
    while True:
        line = Q_read.get(timeout=30)
        #########################

        line = .......do something

        #########################
        Q_write.put(line)
        global_step.value +=1

def main_run(num, char2ind_dict):
    process_list = []
    process_push = Process(target=Push_queue, args=(Q_read, read_dir))
    process_push.start()
    for i in range(num):
        process_i = Process(target=asy_run, args=(Q_read, Q_write, global_step, char2ind_dict))
        process_i.start()
        process_list.append(process_i)
    process_write = Process(target=Write_from_Queue, args=(Q_write, write_dir))
    process_write.start()
    process_push.join()    
    Q_read.join()
    Q_write.join()
    for p in process_list:
        p.join()
    process_write.join()

if __name__ =='__main__':
    char2ind_dict = get_dict(dict_dir)
    main_run(50, char2ind_dict)
```

Comment: You should break your code down to the essential parts needed to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: sorry,it's my first ask problem here

Comment: If you find yourself building a list of threads or processes, what you want is a pool. Python provides two ways to handle this, [`concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor) and [`multiprocessing.pool.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) (the header uses a process pool as its example). Which you prefer might depend on your background and your particular use case; I suggest checking out both. Starting there might clear up your problem, but if not, you will have much cleaner code to start with.